# Prove Occurrence of Transaction Solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Hei everyone, I am working on a project and need to find a way for users to prove to my smart contract that they have sent an ERC 20 token to my contract.

I understand that I can not read data from previous blocks, I was wondering if there is a trusted oracle that can act as ether-scan does and let me confirm that a transaction actually occurred.

Another possible solution I have thought of is requiring each payment of collateral be sent to a unique address, though I do not know how I can safely store multiple private keys in a smart contract.

If any of you have any insight into possible oracle based solutions, how I can hold multiple private keys in a smart contract, if you have any other ideas I have not mentioned here, or if you think the best solution is to just suck it up and build my own oracle I would really appreciate your opinion!

Comment: Please provide us with some code that you have already tried... So that we can help you with actual implementation problems.

Answer (score 0):

this is more of a high level question and I don't believe that providing code is relevant to my question I did find a good answer in this reddit thread

https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/e1j4lw/proof_of_collateral_sent/

basically what is comes down to is erc20 tokens provide the functionality to approve another address to spend their tokens on thier behalf. So by having JavaScript tell the erc20 token's contract to approve our smart contract to spend tokens on the users behalf and then having the user notify our contract, our contract can then move the appropriate amount of erc20 funds from the user's address to its own address.